# Show notification from local storage in react-native android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I my new in react-native. I made a reminder app in react-native android in which the user can set an event on date and time. I have stored that date and time in local storage. Now  I want to show the notification to the user on that particular day and time from local storage.

Comment: Please add what you've tried and what you are going to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule push notification at the time you created reminder notes. React-Native-Firebase module help in implementing push notifications. 
Ref: [schedule push notification](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/scheduling-notifications)
Hope this helps....